# Timer does not stop if repeat is yes in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have added **nstimer** in my app.I have set it's repeat property to **YES**.I am trying to stop timer when i click on button but timer does not stopping in that case.

```
 image_timer_one=  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(ImageTimer:)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

code to stop timer

```
 [image_timer_one invalidate];
 image_timer_one=nil;
```

But timer does not stop.Please tell how can i stop the timer.

**EDIT:**
I trying to give cursor animation effect so i am setting a new image when timer repeats here is the code.

```
-(void)ImageTimer:(NSTimer*)timer{

    if(mode_count==0)
    {
        if(img_time==0)
        {
            [self.pass_image_1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blink_2.png"]];
            img_time=1;
        }
        else if(img_time==1)
        {
            [self.pass_image_1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blink_1.png"]];
            img_time=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your ImageTimer method getting called ????

Comment: May be your button IBAction method wont called while you click button. pls have a break point in button action method.

Comment: where do you startnto the timer and where do you stop it - do you maybe start it more than you stop it? - or are you not setting `image_timer_one` correctly? do an `assert(image_timer_one)` before stopping and `assert(! image_timer_one)` before starting

Answer (score 0):

try this and before starting timer stop previous timer action with calling ImageTimer method.

```
  if (image_timer_one != nil && [image_timer_one isValid]) {

        [image_timer_one invalidate];
        image_timer_one = nil;

    }
```